# Increment elements in object

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to do obvious thing while creating custom pagination and fail. I've got an object of elements which displays in HTML with  the page numbers for pageficator. What I'm trying to do, is to set first page number, and then iterate through other elements increasing them by one.

```
var totalPage = 6;
var currntPags = {
    1: '1',
    2: '2',
    3: '3',
    4: '4',
    5: '5'
}
    ////
    else if ((toTalPage - 2) < pageChosen < (toTalPage)) {
    var pagifFirstPage = totalPage - 4;
    $.each(currntPags, function(index, value){
            value = pagifFirstPage;
            pagifFirstPage ++;
        })
    }
```

But as result I get the same object. I was trying equal for each function - no change. What is the proper way to rewrite array with each?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `else if ((toTalPage - 2) < pageChosen < (toTalPage)) {` you should split this in two conditions. Then, why do you loop over your array in order to replace the `value` by the exactly same var `pagifFirstPage` over and over ?.. Getting `value` by looping does not make sense. Doing `pagifFirstPage + currntPags.length` does the same thing.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve here. Maybe you are trying to solve a certain problem the wrong way. What is the general problem you are trying to solve? Because this method doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @GillesLesire I'm trying to set value of currntPags.1 and then increment each following elemet by one. For example I want to update caurrent state of currntPags to currntPags = {1: '4', 2: '5', 3: '6', 4: '7', 5: '8'}

Comment: I think what you want is just change value = pagifFirstPage; to value += pagifFirstPage; If I understood correctly what you want to achieve. Because now you are just setting ALL currntPags values to 2.

Comment: Please, read http://sscce.org/. Your code example is incomplete and unintelligible, and leaves those trying to help you scratching their heads. Help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. I removed your condition to make a demo.

```js
var currntPags = {
  1: '1',
  2: '2',
  3: '3',
  4: '4',
  5: '5'
}
for(p in currntPags){
  currntPags[p] = parseInt(currntPags[p]) + 1;
}
console.log(currntPags)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [JSONPagination plugin](https://github.com/dheeraja00/JSONPagination) which paginates on the JSON level. It will also help in sorting and searching.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this plugin